# Solve $\sin x = x - 2 \pi/3$

Tags: trigonometry

What is $x$ if $\sin x = x - 2 \pi/3$?

The answer is $x \approx 2.61$ but how do I work that out (without Taylor series - this is homework for 10th grade)? Thanks.

Comment: What tools do you have or you know? :)

Comment: Various simple trigonometric identities (e.g. $\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$).

Comment: Then please share your ideas

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: I have no idea, which is why I am asking here :D

Answer (score 0):

Hint use taylor expansion as $x$ is very snall for $sinx$ which is $sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O(x^7)$ and then you get normal polynomial on both sides whose roots can be obtained. Or see the graphs of lhs,rhs where they meet .

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that I didn't want to use Taylor series. This was homework for 10th grade.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no numerical way for you to compute this without using the Taylor Series, I would just solve it graphically. Getting everything on one side, we have that $\sin(x) - x + \frac{2\pi}{3} = 0.$ Let $f(x) = \sin(x) - x + \frac{2\pi}{3},$ plug that into a graphing calculator, and calculate the zero. You find the zero at $\boxed{x = 2.605}.$

Comment: Yes that's how I got my answer too (actually I just used Wolfram)... but I was hoping for an answer that didn't rely on a graphing calculator.

Comment: Then the only way you could solve this is by using the Taylor Series, which is a calculus topic.